# What is the proper syntax for relative paths in web.config?

Tags: iis, web-config, relative-path, isapi, handlers

I have a site structure like this:

[image]

And I'd like to use a relative path to my `test_isapi.dll` in the web.config for the ISAPI application. I've tried replacing `C:\TestSite1\TestSite2\ISAPI\test_isapi.dll` with the following relative paths with no luck:

- `test_isapi.dll`
- `~/test_isapi.dll`
- `~\test_isapi.dll`
- `ISAPI\test_isapi.dll`

**Do I have the syntax wrong for the relative path, or is this just not possible for handler settings in the config?**

*Current (working with absolute path) web.config (TestSite1/TestSite2/ISAPI/web.config):*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Test ISAPI"
           path="*"
           verb="*"
           modules="IsapiModule"
           scriptProcessor="C:\TestSite1\TestSite2\ISAPI\test_isapi.dll"
           resourceType="Unspecified"
           requireAccess="None"
           preCondition="bitness32" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to programmatically check and add the handler mapping instead of deploying the setting with the web.config. That way I can determine the absolute path at run-time and apply the setting. Not ideal, but it gets the job done.

See this answer: [How to add IIS handler mapping programmattically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718124/how-to-add-iis-handler-mapping-programmattically/19731488#19731488)

Answer (score -1):

config you can write ~/filepath

Comment: you can see in my question i've tried `~/test_isapi.dll` which did not work. can you be more specific for my example?

Comment: See my comment on @Gopalakrishnan's answer. This solution will not work in the `System.webServer` section.

Answer (score -1):

To use a relative path just Add  `~/test_isapi.dll` for ISAPI Site webconfig.

Comment: as I mentioned above, this does not work. I know it works for other cases in web.config, but something about the handlers section or scriptProcessor attribute must be different.

Comment: check this link for handlers http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/handlers

Comment: Relative paths will not work in the `System.webServer` section. In that section, you're essentially configuring the web server itself, which has no notion of the web application in order to derive a relative path. Paths need to be absolute. The OP's solution is the only way around this, unless you're prepared to put the referenced files in the application root, in which case they work with the path `file.htm`.